This seal is a name. What are the characters and what do they mean? (Characters identified: 權固守)
This seal is a name awarded to a martial artist.
I think the name means strong and protective.  The word for strong might be the same word used for iron mills?
Any help on the Chinese characters and their translation would be greatly appreciate.


權固守 means "hold the power firmly" or "strongly defend the rights".
權 --> 權力 = power (as in governing power)
權 --> 權利 = right (as in human rights)
固 = firmly; solidly; strongly
守 = hold; protect; defend
Depending on who awarded this name, it could describe either a pro-authority government (Party) loyalist or a human rights activist.
Another possibility:
權 --> 主權 = sovereignty
in this case, 權固守 means "strongly defends sovereignty", describing a patriotic person

So it could be describing someone who is authoritative/powerful and protective of people? 權 by itself means power and the symbol next to it describes the type of power?

My answer stated 權 can mean "power" or "right". Without the more defined words like 權力 and 權利, it is open for interpretations

有權殺人 = have the (legal) power to kill people; 有權不被殺 = have the right not to be killed

do any of the words have a connection to the modern word for iron or steel mills?

In many political speeches, steel mills often represent the industrial strength of a nation. "strongly defends sovereignty" (固守主權) might make sense if you connect the  industrial might to the strength of a nation
